# /testforblock command doesn't reply with tesults

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I swear I have done this perfectly, but for some reason it doesn't work. The coordinates are indeed correct, and it is a dropper so there's something in the NBT tag. It is a server, command blocks are enabled, and everything else works. (I have also tried `testforblocks`)

`testforblock 14 8 -416 minecraft:dropper 0 {Items:[0:{Slot:1b,id:planks,Count:1b},{Slot:3b,id:planks,Count:1b},{Slot:4b,id:diamond_block,Count:2b},{Slot:5b,id:planks,Count:1b},{Slot:6b,id:stone_slab,Count:1b},{Slot:7b,id:stone_slab,Count:1b},{Slot:8b,id:stone_slab,Count:1b}]}`

[image: Should be the recipe]

Should be the recipe

Comment: What happens? Does the line running out stay powered, or does it not turn on at all?

Comment: It's on a very fast  clock, with redstone fill commands

Comment: It's testing for certain items in a hopper which is cloned from a named Endermite. It doesn't return anything, and it doesn't give out a short pulse either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it's lenient when setting data, Minecraft requires you to give full item names when testing for them. Add "minecraft:" before each item name and it should work:

```
testforblock 47 4 -53 minecraft:dropper -1 {Items:[{Slot:1b,id:"minecraft:planks",Count:1b},{Slot:3b,id:"minecraft:planks",Count:1b},{Slot:4b,id:"minecraft:diamond_block",Count:2b},{Slot:5b,id:"minecraft:planks",Count:1b},{Slot:6b,id:"minecraft:stone_slab",Count:1b},{Slot:7b,id:"minecraft:stone_slab",Count:1b},{Slot:8b,id:"minecraft:stone_slab",Count:1b}]}
```

Comment: I have tried it, it had the prefixes BEFORE the code above.

Comment: Though, I added  the quotes and it seemed to work. Thanks!

Comment: @user130709 The quotes do not fix it alone, even if they are good practice for declaring strings, and thus have no bearing on the possible success of the command. There was another issue you were having that may have been overlooked.